# Editing a Core Data Table View Entry With Overwriting the existing entry rather than creating a new entry

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, editing

I have a Core Data based application with a table view controller; the user presses the plus button in the navigation bar and they're taken modally to a view controller where they can enter information into text fields. Pressing the save button saves this information Core Data and displays it in the Table view.

I've configured the app so that when I click on a cell, I'm taken to a view that has the information passed across successfully.

What I want to achieve is renaming a text field (for example, a name) and pressing Save updates THAT attribute in Core Data, rather than creating a brand new one with the same name and keeping the old one.

My save method in the editing view controller is:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    Transaction *transaction = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Transaction" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    Item *itemType = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    Person *enteredPerson = (Person *)[Person personWithName:self.editingNameTextField.text inManagedObjectContext:context];
    transaction.whoBy = enteredPerson;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Can't save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Which calls:

```
+ (Person *)personWithName:(NSString *)name inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Person *person = nil;

    // Creating a fetch request to check whether the name of the person already exists
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", name];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *people = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (!people)
    {
        // Handle Error
    }
    else if (![people count])
    {
        // If the person count is 0 then let's create it
        person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        person.name = name;
    }
    else
    {
        // If the object exists, just return the last object .
        person = [people lastObject];
    }
    return person; 

    /*
    for (Person *info in people)
    {
        NSLog(@"Names are: %@", person.name);
    }

     */
}
```

So when I click on a cell for Jack, it shows me all of Jack's information. I want to rename Jack to Jackie and have that update Core Data for ALL "Jackie's transactions" but with overwriting the Jack object, rather than keeping that and creating another called Jackie.

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: And you pass the `Person` instance to the view controller that's doing the editing? And you edit and save it? Where is any editing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rename a person, you just have to fetch the object (using the old name) and then
update the name attribute. For example:

```
Person *person = [Person personWithName:oldName inManagedObjectContext:context];
person.name = newName;
```

All relationships to other objects (like transactions etc) are not modified by this.

Comment: Thanks Martin - that makes sense about the relationships. Do you mean performing an actual fetchRequest for the oldName? Also, in your example, what does newName equal?

Comment: @amitsbajaj: You said you want to rename "Jack" to "Jackie". Then you have to fetch the Person entity using the old name "Jack" and then set person.name to the new name "Jackie".

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense - I've got a quick fetchRequest using the current typed name as the predicate condition ("name EQUALS[c] %@", self.editingNameTextField.text).. I'm just not quite sure I understand where/how I'd create a newName object to be updated with.. sorry!

Comment: @amitsbajaj: Sorry, I do not know how to help more. If you want to change a person's name than you must have a `Person` object that you want to modify, and you must have a new name (which is just a string with the new name, e.g. "Jackie").

Comment: Thanks Martin and not a problem - I do get it and I, as always, appreciate your assistance! Now I'm going to work on figuring out how to piece everything together - thanks again

Comment: I have it working now with your code (and a few adjustments) but one thing is (and perhaps this was my mistake in the original question), when I rename Jack to Jackie, it changes it for every occurrence of Jack in the entire model, instead of just that one Transaction. Does this make sense or should I update the question to include the code? What I want is to edit JUST that one transaction with Jack to Jackie, not every occurrence of Jack in the database.. does that make sense?

Comment: @amitsbajaj: So you want to assign a transaction to a different person? That's different from renaming a person, and perhaps I misunderstood your question. But I am writing this from the phone and do not have access to my computer for the next days, therefore I cannot help much at present.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, that was my mistake in the question - I want to edit a "name" attribute, but I want to edit it just for a single transaction, rather than for every transaction with that name.. so just editing a single transaction from Jack to Jackie, but leaving all other Jacks in tact. 

not a problem at all - I will try to work through this - I have the theoretical concept but just nt sure who to implement